# Nginx: customize return value for plain http on ssl port 443 error (400)

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to customize a return value for plain HTTP on ssl port 443 error (400)

My goal is to just drop the connection, I have not been able to do that.

I have only been able to return value 200. If I try something else, I get server error.

Note: I am an advanced Linux user and but I am not an expert user of nginx.

**Server section:**

```
server {

    error_page 400 /400_error.html;

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name servername.server.com

    ssl_certificate fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key privkey.pem;

    ssl on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }

    location /400_error.html {
        return 200;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not really customizable. And sending a 400 Bad Request does drop the connection anyway. It's probably not worth wasting your time on this.

Answer (score -1):

## Closing Connection on Nginx

> …special nginx…code 444…that closes the
>   connection [<sup>via nginx.org</sup>](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#how_to_prevent_undefined_server_names)

```
server {
    ⋮
    listen      80;
    return      444;
    ⋮
}
```

Comment: see [return statement docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return)